# Using ViewPager to open different activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement my `ViewPager` in a `Fragment` so that each page can open different activities but so far, onClickListener does not respond nor its never called.

Here is how I have it implemented under my `PagerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, final int pos) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_jeans, null);

    page.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),JeansActivity.class));
        }
    });

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);
    return page;
}
```

I was reading the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) about `ViewPager` but couldn't find any help regarding on how to implement it properly.

Here is the entire code in my `Fragment` Menu:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by WiLo on 2/13/2015.
 */
public class FmMenu extends Fragment {

    int[] imagenes = {
            R.drawable.jeans,
            R.drawable.blusas,
            R.drawable.leggings,
    };

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_menufragment, container, false);

        //galeria de imagenes

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[0]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[1]));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addfragments(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(imagenes[2]));

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        return rootView;


    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        List<Fragment> fragmentos;
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentos = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        }

        public void addfragments(Fragment xfragment){
            fragmentos.add(xfragment);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentos.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentos.size();
        }



    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

        private static final String ARG_IMAGE = "imagen";
        private int imagen;

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int imagen) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_IMAGE, imagen);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            return fragment;
        }

        public void onClick(View v){

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if(getArguments() != null) {
                imagen = getArguments().getInt(ARG_IMAGE);
            }
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

            ImageView jeans = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            jeans.setImageResource(imagen);

            jeans.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),JeansActivity.class));

                }

            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Any help or reference to any other documentation will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `PlaceholderFragment` instances as your `ViewPager`pages? If you are, you have to make each of those Fragments implement View.onClickListener interface so you can capture clicks inside them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Pardon for the rookie question but how would I do that? Do I add the View.onClickListener through my public static class `PlaceHolderFragment` or under my `onCreateView` method?

Comment: Just change your Fragment's class declaration to `public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {` and implement the OnClick() callback. On `onCreateView()`, define a ClickListener to the View you want to click to open new `Activity`.

Comment: Ok, going to give it a try and i'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: @joao2fast4u Thanks for the help! Was able to implement the `onClick` and it worked but each time I click on any of the images in the `ViewPager`, it sends me to the same `Activity`. How is the proper way to define each of them individualy to its `Activity`? I mean, do I define a `ClickListener` for each of them? By the way, I updated the code in my post so you can see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `PlaceHolderFragment` `onCreateView()` callback, you just have to check what image id you have on your `Fragments` argument. With that resource id, you can launch your `Activity` according to that value:

```
jeans.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent activityIntent = new Intent();

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        switch(imagen){
        case R.drawable.jeans:
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), JeansActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.drawable.blusas:
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BlusasActivity.class);
            break;
            R.drawable.leggings:
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LegginsActivity.class);
            break;
        }

        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like it is missing the `case` keyword before `R.drawable.leggings:`.